# Pygame: Accessing colliding sprite's properties using spritecollide()

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a top down shooter in the style of Raiden 2. I need to know how to get access to the enemy object when I detect collision using 'spritecollide'.

The reason I need the enemy object is so that I can lower their energy level for every bullet that hits them.

This is the dictionary that I have to work with:

```
enemyCollisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(shipBulletGroup, enemyGroup, True, False)
```

Here's my Bullet class:

```
class Bullet(Entity):
    def __init__(self, ship, angle):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 8
        self.level = 0
        self.image = pygame.Surface((BULLET_DIMENSIONS, BULLET_DIMENSIONS)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.y = ship.rect.top
        self.angle = angle

    def update(self, enemyGroup):
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()
        else:
            self.rect.y -= self.speed
```

Here's my unfinished Enemy class:

```
class Enemy_1(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = (1, 1)
        self.energy = 10
        self.begin = False
        self.run = False
        self.image = pygame.Surface((WIN_W/5, WIN_H/15)).convert()
        self.image.fill((70, 70, 70))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIN_W/1.333
        self.rect.y = -WIN_H/15

    def shoot(self):
        bullet_1 = Bullet(self, 270)
        bullet_2 = Bullet(self, 225)
        bullet_3 = Bullet(self, 315)

    def update(self, enemyGroup, timer):
        if timer == 300:
            self.begin = True
        elif timer == 900:
            self.run = True
        elif timer > 900 and self.rect.x > WIN_W:
            self.remove(enemyGroup)

        if self.run:
            self.rect.x += self.speed[0]
            self.rect.y += self.speed[1]
        elif self.begin:
            self.rect.y += self.speed[1]
            if self.rect.y > WIN_H/4:
                self.rect.y = WIN_H/4

        if self.energy == 0:
            self.kill()
```

Here's the complete program:

```
import sys, pygame, os, random, math

from ast import literal_eval

# Force static position of screen
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

# Constants
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

PILL_WIDTH = 5
PILL_HEIGHT = 20

WIN_W = 500
WIN_H = 800

SHIP_WIDTH = WIN_W/15
SHIP_HEIGHT = WIN_H/15

BULLET_DIMENSIONS = 5
TIMER = 0


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


class Text(Entity):
    def __init__(self, text, size, color, position, font=None):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.color = color
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(font, size)
        self.text = text
        self.set(text, position)

    def set(self, text, position):
        self.image = self.font.render(str(text), 1, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.move_ip(position[0]-self.rect.width/2, (position[1]-self.rect.height)/2)


class Ship(Entity):
    def __init__(self, container):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 5
        self.score = 0
        self.image = pygame.Surface((SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = container.centerx
        self.rect.y = container.centery

    def update(self, bulletGroup):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.centery -= self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.centery += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.centerx += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.centerx -= self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if TIMER % 7 == 0:
                bullet = Bullet(self, 90, 'friend')
                bulletGroup.add(bullet)

        # Ship Movement Boundaries
        if self.rect.y < WIN_H/25:
            self.rect.y = WIN_H/25
        if self.rect.y > WIN_H - SHIP_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.y = WIN_H - SHIP_HEIGHT
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        if self.rect.x > WIN_W - SHIP_WIDTH:
            self.rect.x = WIN_W - SHIP_WIDTH

class Bullet(Entity):
    def __init__(self, ship, angle, type):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 8
        self.level = 0
        self.image = pygame.Surface((BULLET_DIMENSIONS, BULLET_DIMENSIONS)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.dx = math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * self.speed
        self.dy = math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * self.speed
        self.setXY(ship, type)

    def setXY(self, ship, type):
        self.rect.x = ship.rect.centerx
        if type == 'friend':
            self.rect.y = ship.rect.top
        elif type == 'enemy':
            self.rect.y = ship.rect.bottom

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()
        else:
            self.rect.x -= self.dx
            self.rect.y -= self.dy
            if type == 'friend':
                self.rect.y = -self.rect.y
                self.rect.x = -self.rect.x


class Powerup(Entity):
    def __init__(self, xden, pillCount):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 3
        self.density = xden
        self.image = pygame.Surface((PILL_WIDTH, PILL_HEIGHT)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.rect.move(100,100)

    def restart(self):
        pass

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.y > WIN_H:
            del self
        else:
            self.rect = self.rect.move((0, self.speed))


class Enemy(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.begin = False
        self.run = False
        self.color = (153, 0, 76)

class Planes(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, speed, energy, size, location):
        Enemy.__init__(self)
        self.speed = speed
        self.energy = energy
        self.image = pygame.Surface(size).convert()
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = location[0]
        self.rect.y = location[1]

    def shoot(self, enemyBulletGroup):
        bullet_1 = Bullet(self, 240, 'enemy')
        bullet_2 = Bullet(self, 270, 'enemy')
        bullet_3 = Bullet(self, 300, 'enemy')
        enemyBulletGroup.add(bullet_1, bullet_2, bullet_3)

    def update(self, enemyGroup, enemyBulletGroup):
        if TIMER == 300:
            self.begin = True
        elif TIMER == 900:
            self.run = True
        elif self.rect.x > WIN_W or self.energy == 0:
            self.kill()

        if self.run:
            self.rect.x += self.speed[0]
            self.rect.y += self.speed[1]
            if TIMER % 100 == 0:
                self.shoot(enemyBulletGroup)
        elif self.begin:
            self.rect.y += self.speed[1]
            if self.rect.y > WIN_H/4:
                self.rect.y = WIN_H/4
                if TIMER % 100 == 0:
                    self.shoot(enemyBulletGroup)

def main():

    # Initialize Everything
    pygame.init()
    global TIMER
    fps = 60
    lLeft = lRight = lUp = lDown = shoot = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    play = True
    pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_W, WIN_H), pygame.SRCALPHA)

    # Create Game Objects
    ship = Ship(pygame.rect.Rect(0, 0, WIN_W, WIN_H))
    score1 = Text("Score: " + str(ship.score), 40, BLACK, (WIN_W/2, (WIN_H/25)))
    enemy_1 = Planes((1, 1), 10, (WIN_W/5, WIN_H/15), (WIN_W/1.4, -WIN_H/15))

    # Create Groups
    powerupGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    shipGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    shipGroup.add(ship)
    textGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    textGroup.add(score1)
    shipBulletGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    enemyBulletGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    enemyGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    enemyGroup.add(enemy_1)


    # Gameplay
    while play:
        # Checks if window exit button pressed
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        # Update
        powerupGroup.update()
        ship.update(shipBulletGroup)
        shipBulletGroup.update()
        textGroup.update()
        enemyGroup.update(enemyGroup, enemyBulletGroup)
        enemyBulletGroup.update()


        enemyCollisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(shipBulletGroup, enemyGroup, True, False)
        for key in enemyCollisions:
            print enemyCollisions[key].energy


        # Print Background/Sprites
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        powerupGroup.draw(screen)
        shipGroup.draw(screen)
        shipBulletGroup.draw(screen)
        textGroup.draw(screen)
        enemyGroup.draw(screen)
        enemyBulletGroup.draw(screen)

        # Print Score Bar
        hori_partition = pygame.Surface((WIN_W, 1))
        screen.blit(hori_partition, (0, WIN_H/25))

        TIMER += 1
        # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
        clock.tick(fps)
        # Writes to main surface
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm assuming that your `Entity` inherits from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. Are you saying that the dict returned by `groupcollide` doesn't contain your objects? I thought it would.

Comment: I've been trying different ways to access the object's information, to no avail. I'd appreciate an example using the dictionary posted above. We can assume the Enemy object has an 'energy' property initialized to 10. 'energy' should be decremented by one on collision with a bullet.

Comment: and yes, 'Enemy' inherits from pygame.sprite.Sprite.

Comment: So the dict returned form groupcollide (enemyCollisions) should contain all the references to the sprite objects that you should need.  The keys to that dict should be the objects from shipBulletGroup and the list associated with each key should be the collided sprites from enemyGroup.   So you have both objects, the collider and the collidee, for each collision. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I run the following code: enemyCollisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(shipBulletGroup, enemyGroup, True, False)
        for key in enemyCollisions:
            print enemyCollisions[key].energy                                                           and the algorithm errors out saying that the object doesn't have an energy property, but it does. if you could answer the original question with code i can test, it would be more helpful.

Comment: It would honestly help if **you** posted runnable code that **we** could test. Then we could tell you what to change. Your code, as posted, doesn't do anything.

Comment: I've added the complete program.

Comment: It looks like the plane class is the only one with energy.  I would check the outputs of your collision to make sure they are plane objects.

Comment: they are plane objects.

Answer (score 1):

The **[`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide)** function **returns a dictionary which values are list objects**:

> Every Sprite inside *group1* is added to the return dictionary. The *value* for each item is the list of Sprites in *group2* that intersect.

Thats the reason why calling `print enemyCollisions[key].energy` when iterating over the return dict fails, since a list object -- the value of  `enemyCollisions[key]` -- does not have an `energy()` method.

To access all values of a dictionary in Python 2.X you could use the `.itervalues()` method of a dict instance. To get each colliding sprite, iterate again over these values:

```
enemyCollisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(shipBulletGroup, enemyGroup, True, False)

#iterate over all values of the enemyCollisions dict
for enemyCollisions in enemyCollisions.itervalues():

    #access all enemies which collided with an shipBullet
    for enemy in enemyCollisions:
        print enemy.energy
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for accessing the collided sprite's property is as follows:

```
collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, pillGroup, True)
    for key in collisions:
        self.density += key.density
```